# deploy an application on a single smartphone

Tags: javascript, react-native, deployment, smartphone

I want to develop a React Native application but only install this one on my only smartphone. Basically, I don't want this app to be accessible in the world just for me.
What approach to take? Do we have to go through the store?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Expo](https://expo.io/) to build and distribute your application. That way you don't need to go to app stores, you only need a link to access and download your app.

Besides that, they offer plenty of useful libs, like notifications, geolocalization, and so on.